# incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to OnDateSetListener

Tags: java, android

error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to OnDateSetListener
.callback(getActivity())

```
new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
            .context(getActivity())
            .callback(getActivity())
            .spinnerTheme(R.style.NumberPickerStyle)
            .showTitle(true)
            .showDaySpinner(true)
            .defaultDate(2000, 0, 1)
            .maxDate(Integer.parseInt(temp), 0, 1)
            .minDate(1950, 0, 1)
            .build()
            .show();
```

Answer (score 0):

your fragment must implement interface OnDateSetListener and set
SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder

```
new SpinnerDatePickerDialogBuilder()
            .context(getActivity())
            .callback(this)
            .spinnerTheme(R.style.NumberPickerStyle)
            .showTitle(true)
            .showDaySpinner(true)
            .defaultDate(2000, 0, 1)
            .maxDate(Integer.parseInt(temp), 0, 1)
            .minDate(1950, 0, 1)
            .build()
            .show();
```